# How to only get inner text of a tag in BeautifulSoup, excluding the embedded one?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping, urllib2, python-requests

For example,

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <b>Hey, sexy!</b>
        Hello
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want only 'Hello' from the `li` tag.

If I use `soup.find("ul").li.text` It includes the `b` tag as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [`find`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) function like so

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<ul><li><b>Hey, sexy!</b>Hello</li></ul>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.find('li').find(text=True, recursive=False)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, man!
Not sure how I missed that in documentation.

Comment: One thing though, what does text=True do?

Comment: It returns the text value for that child only (or None if there isnt any text) and does not consider child elements. If you take away the recursive=False then you get just 'Hey, sexy!' as it recurses into the <b> tag.

Comment: Does not work for me. I used `contents` and then the index where it is between the tags.

Comment: @Adam thanks. I'll take a look it's been a while since that answer, so it's not fresh in my mind. Why not consider posting a new answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`extract()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract), which will remove a tag from the tree.

In your case:

```
soup.find("ul").b.extract() # removes the <b> tag
soup.find("ul").li.text     # contents of <li> without <b>
```